# Heroku: приложение засыпает, несмотря на тарифный план Hobby

Tags: telegram-bot, heroku

Задеплоил телеграм-бота на хероку, обновил тарифный план с free на hobby

В [документации](https://www.heroku.com/pricing#containers) написано, что hobby-тачки никогда не засыпают

Однако, если не обращаться к боту в течение примерно одного часа, то он засыпает, и приходится его перезапускать в админке

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобным?

Comment: данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что его следует адресовать в соответствующую техподдержку

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.